# Need to make song Item list as buttons so that when I tap on it starts playing

Tags: javascript, frontend, web-development-server

When I click on those elements it starts playing

I am expecting that song list items to behave as a button when I tap on it starts playing it contains list of songs when I tap on the songs it will starts to play the songs and once again I tap on it stops the song need functionality for the code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.